# Dynamic Serve static-locations in spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which contains web application build with Polymer. Polymer web application builds two version one with ES5 And one ES6. It mean i have two separate web application builds. Now on based of user agent like for Chrome & firefox i want to serve ES6 version and for IE11 I have to serve Es5 version.

Both versions of apps are placed inside static folder of spring boot like

```
/static/es5
/static/es6
```

Both of version contains index.html file and contains same folder structure inside only difference is of code.

I want user to hit same URL and they should get served resources dynamically based on their user-agent/browser.

i have defined following properties in application.properties.

```
 spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/public/es5/
```

How can i make es5 & es6 resources serve dynamically ???

`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write custom `ResourceResolver`. It will give you access to request, so you can serve resource based on request header.

Docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceResolver.html

Explanation:

https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources

Comment: Custom ResourceResolver is called only once when first request is hit for server for static resource.